# DataBind and Postback

Tags: .net, data-binding, objectdatasource

This is a general how does DataBind work questions...

I have a simple page with a GridView that is bound (in the aspx code) to an ObjectDataSource.

I can look in the Select() function called by the ObjectDataSource to see that it is called on the initial load and on every post back.  I have some logic that happens on post backs that will affect the GridView's data, and I want to call GridView.DataBind() later on in the post back, after I've made some changes.

Is there a way to prevent the automatic rebinding that happens on each post back?  Does this mean I can't use an ObjectDataSource for this control?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're correct in that the fine grained control you're looking for is not possible and requires the code behind.  ASP.NET's data source objects are nothing but a pain in the a**.  You'll find that as you use them you'll get situations like this cropping up again and again.

Some of the problems you'll find are:

- Not strongly typed
- Inflexible (as you've noted)
- Muddy up the presentation code

I've taken to doing all data access in the code behind and haven't looked back.

Answer (score 9):

I fought with this automatic binding as well and thought I post my solution here:

1. remove the "DataSourceID" from the ASPX page, when its not set, there is no automatic binding
2. set the DataSourceID in the CodeBehind only when DataBinding is needed: myGridView.DataSourceID = "MyDataSource";
3. do not call myGridView.DataBind() explicitly, databinding happens automatically at PreRender

Took me a while to figure this out, but now wverything works fine.

**Context**

I use the ObjectDatasource because it handels all the **paging** and **sorting** of the Gridview automatically for me. I am using a data layer with Linq2SQL and use its Skip() and Take() methods to load only the amount of data needed to populate one page of the GridView.

Using the **SelectMethod** and **SelectCountMethod** of the ObjectDataSource

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've gone with Gavin's suggestion of just avoiding the mess.  My company has since switched to Telerik which supports a really clean code-behind binding method called "NeedDataSource".  Still, if I need to switch back, I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  If you want that kind of control over when the databinding happens you need to do it in the code behind.