# How to get selected value from DropDownList which is inside GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, selectedindex

I have a DropDownList inside GridView. There can be '*n* ' number of rows in a GridView with each row having a DropDownList with different values. I am populating DropDownLists dynamically and all the values are populated properly in DropDownLists.

When I change the selected value of DropDownList for each row and press the button to save these values, I always get the value of 0 index instead of the value that I have selected.

I found lot of questions like this but none of them helps me. What's the reason it doesn't get the right selected value from DropDownList? Any ideas?

When I remove the GridView and just use DropDownList then it works fine.

Comment: please provide the code which you are using with your question.

Comment: @SainPradeep thanks for response. You know I have resolved it right now. While providing you my code :| My bad

Comment: Thanks for all quick responses. I found that I am resetting the DropDownList ID when dynamically populating values in it. Remove that thing and it worked.

Comment: rizzz86, my answer edited

Comment: Make sure you are not reloading the content of the drop downs in your page load event which will fire before you try to read the drop downs.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="XYZ">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="MyDD" DataSourceId="MyDataSource" />
  </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[1].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            con.Open();
            var ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlState");
            int CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from State where CountryID = @CountryId", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CountryID", CountryId);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            ddl.DataSource = ds;
            ddl.DataTextField = "StateName";
            ddl.DataValueField = "StateID";
            ddl.DataBind();
            ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
        }
    }

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
 {

  DropDownList ddl= (DropDownList )GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlState");
  string selectedvalue=ddl.selectedvalue;
  //My custom code to change last moment values with that selected from DropDownList 
  e.NewValues.Add("State", selectedvalue);

 }
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161496/dropdownlist-in-gridview)

Answer (score 0):

do like this....

put a link button in gridview and set its commandargument a rowdatabount event like this... and set any commandname for that linkbutton.

In this code i have set CommandName ="test"

```
int count;

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

{

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)

{

//DataRowView oRow = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

LinkButton lnkPostType = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("linkbpostype");

lnkPostType.CommandArgument = count.ToString();

count++;

}

}

 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)

{

if (e.CommandName == "test")

{


int RowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString().Trim());

DropDownList ddlNew = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("ddlst");

string abc = ddlNew.SelectedValue;

}

}
```

Comment: this code is working on my system.. if u face any problem then let me know

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this from a tutorial here 
    [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**I think this will help you**

```
    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        string stateID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex]["StateID"].ToString();
        string cityID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex]["CityID"].ToString();
        // Edit Event
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        populateData();

        // Here populate data for dropdown state
        DropDownList ddStateEdit = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("ddState");
        if (ddStateEdit != null)
        {
            ddStateEdit.DataSource = populateState();
            ddStateEdit.DataTextField = "StateName";
            ddStateEdit.DataValueField = "StateID";
            ddStateEdit.DataBind();
            ddStateEdit.SelectedValue = stateID;
        }

        DropDownList ddCityEdit = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("ddCity");
        if (ddCityEdit != null)
        {
            ddCityEdit.DataSource = populateCity(Convert.ToInt32(stateID));
            ddCityEdit.DataTextField = "CityName";
            ddCityEdit.DataValueField = "CityID";
            ddCityEdit.DataBind();
            ddCityEdit.SelectedValue = cityID;
        }
    }
```