# ASP.NET Syntax to insert column in files database during upload and then to use that column to filter files into groups when downloading

Tags: sql, asp.net, file-upload

I am keeping this brief so as not to make anyone assisting not have to wade through a lot of explanation and code.  Please ask me for any additional explanation or code you'd like to see to help me solve this, if needed.

UPLOAD: (commented out code gets null exception.  I do have DropDownList1 in the markup.  I don't know what's wrong.  It of course works if I hard code to "ReportGroup2" as shown.

```
            'cmd.Parameters.Add("@Related", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TryCast(FindControl("DropDownList1"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Related", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "ReportGroup2"
```

DOWNLOAD: (Works with hardcoded "ReportGroup2" but I don't know the syntax for the commented out line.  Im trying to get the value in the Related column of the file's row)

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsItPrivate", IsItPrivate)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Related", "ReportGroup2")
    'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Related", TryCast(FindControl("DropDownList1"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex)
```

Again, please let me know if you need more details.  My natural tendency is to explain things in great detail and include all pertinent markup code, code behind, and table structure but I have found that no one answers on any forum if I do that.  The time investment is too much I think.

If you're still reading this - thanks!  I will definitely come back and mark as answer who ever answers or helps.  I'll also post finished code if I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need a bit more information, but I'm going to take a stab in the dark.

I take it `DropDownList1` is in a control like a `GridView` and you are trying to do something with this on a button click.

The trick to `FindControl` is anchoring it on the right container as it is not recursive or deep searching if you will.

YOu most likely have a row that you are working with so try something like `row.FindControl("DropDownList1")`, assuming you have `row` defined.

More info: [How to get selected value from DropDownList which is inside GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852619/how-to-get-selected-value-from-dropdownlist-which-is-inside-gridview)

and: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Note:

> Searches the **current naming container** for a server control with the
>   specified id parameter.

Bold added for emphasis.

In this scenario it is often common to have a variable for the control. This aids in debugging and you can have incode checks for null. Something like (I'm a C# guy so my VB is a little rusty):

```
Dim ddList as DropDownList
ddList = TryCast(row.FindControl("DropDownList1"),DropDownList)

If (Not ddList  Is Nothing)
   'Assign parameter etc
Else
   'Control not found
   'Do something else, perhaps throw an excpetion
End If
```

Comment: Thank you Jon P.  The drop down is "freestanding". It's not in a grid view. I ended up with: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Related", DropDownList1.selected.Value)  This seemed to work in the Upload portion which loads a grid view with field uploaded now and in the past.  When I try to download via links in the grid this no longer works.

Comment: Thank you Jon P.The drop down is "freestanding". Not in a grid view. I ended up: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Related", DropDownList1.selected.Value)  Works in the Upload portion which loads a gridview with files uploaded.  If I try to download via links in the grid this no longer works. In the download sub:   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Related", Related).  Here I'm trying to pull the Related value from the DB Table row containing name of file, file contents, contenttype, IsItPrivate, and Related column.  Error is "Variable 'Related' is used before it has been assigned a value, etc Thanks.